# Failing to build cufflinks-2.2.1

Tags: linux, boost

Building on a RHEL 7 system, using gcc 9.2

```
./configure --prefix=../../tools/bin --with-bam=../samtools-0.1.19/ --with-boost=../samtools-0.1.19/

...
checking whether the Boost::Thread library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_thread... no
checking for exit in -lboost_thread... (cached) no
checking for exit in -lboost_thread... (cached) no
checking for exit in -lboost_thread... (cached) no
checking for exit in -lboost_thread... (cached) no
checking for exit in -llibboost_thread.a... no
configure: error: Could not link against libboost_thread.a !

../samtools-0.1.19/lib is a symlink to ../samtools-0.1.19/stage/lib, which contains:

-rw-r--r--  libboost_thread.a
lrwxrwxrwx  libboost_thread.so -> libboost_thread.so.1.71.0*
lrwxrwxrwx  libboost_thread.so.1 -> libboost_thread.so.1.71.0*
lrwxrwxrwx  ibboost_thread.so.1.71 -> libboost_thread.so.1.71.0*
-rwxr-xr-x  libboost_thread.so.1.71.0*
```

Any ideas why this build is failing?

Comment: *`configure: error: Could not link against libboost_thread.a`*

Comment: @jww Yeah, i know it's saying that.  Which is why I included the ls from the lib/ which includes the libboost_thread.a that I just build